# How to store Log in database?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design

My application let users to send files to each other. Regular users can edit their contacts, change password, etc. In addition, admin users can add/remove users and view the log of what happened. My question is how to store this log in MySQL database ?

I thought to store the log like this:

```
log_id   time   user_id   action_type                      description
------   ----   -------   ----------------   ----------------------------------------
   1     ....      4      User added         Added new user: alex
   2     ....      1      Contact added      Added contact Paul to group Family 
   3     ....      1      User removed       Removed user: gabrielle 
   4     ....      3      Files sent         Sent files 3,5,7,14 to contacts 2,4,8
   5     ....      8      Group added        Added new group: Family 
   6     ....      8      Password changed   
   7     ....      8      First Name changed Changed First Name from Michael to Misha
```

What type would be the best for `action_type` ? Since new `action_type`s may be added in future, I thought that `ENUM` won't be a good choice. So I thought to make it `VARCHAR(..)`, like `description`.

Is this seems reasonable ?

I will be happy to hear any comments / suggestions.

Comment: Pet peeve: Call your primary key `id` instead of `log_id`. You avoid ugly repetition: `logs.log_id`

Comment: @meagar - There's nothing wrong with using log_id, and it is a recommended naming scheme. It ensures column names don't collide when doing joins without typing out a long list of aliases.

Comment: @mellowsoon That is why I said "pet peeve" and not "you're doing it wrong".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're concerned about adding additional action types, make a separate table to store your action types and and join it to your logs table with a foreign key:

`logs` table:

```
log_id   time   user_id   action_type_id     description
------   ----   -------   ----------------   -----------------------------------
   1     ....      4            1            Added new user: alex
   2     ....      1            2            Added contact Paul to group Family 
...
```

`action_types` table:

```
id    name
---   ---------------
1     User added
2     Contact added
.....
```